# Undervolting AMD GPUs

Tags: amd-graphics

My systems run a few AMD GPUs for ETH mining.

Since I don't go for overclocking, I would like to undervolt the GPU to save power and reduce heat.

Is there any way in Ubuntu to achieve this?

GPUs:
RX 470
RX 580
R9 290

Comment: have you learn how to do this? looking to do this in a rx580